# Add current viewcontroller to navigationControllerStack

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

okay, so I have 2 VC.

From vc1 I move to vc2 using segue

Now from vc2 I want to move to vc2 using the following code

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: screenId)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

It's not working as VC2 wasn't added to navigation controller stack.

I want to know how to add the VC2 to navigation controller stack programmatically.
The thing is that I am using segue in some cases and pushing view controller in some other.

Answer (score 0):

Because Your VC1 doesn't embedded in a `NavigationController`. Go to `Storyboard` embed your first VC1 to `NavigationController` and change your segue from `modal`/`presentation` to `show`. Then you can push as much as ViewControllers you want in the navigation stack.

[image: How to Embed A ViewController in Navigation Controller]

[image: Change Segue from modal/presentation to SHOW]

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that `navigationController = nil`

So if it is, then you need to embedded view controller into navigation view controller.

**In this case `UINavigationContoller` should be your root view controller. Please verify your root view controller.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
let loginVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: screenId)
let aObjNavi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVc)
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = aObjNavi
```

insteed of

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: screenId)
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

It may helps you. Thank you.